# Create a Boolean parser

Tags: code-golf

What you need to do is create a Boolean parser.

---

Boolean expressions, in case you haven't heard of them yet, have two inputs and one output. There are four 'gates' in boolean arithmetic, namely OR (represented by `|`), AND (represented by `&`), NOT (which are used a bit like brackets : `/` and `\` ***note, I could have used `!`, but you can't use them as brackets, since `!!!!` is ambiguous (`//\\` or `/\/\`)***) and XOR (represented by `^`). These gates operate on their inputs which are either true or false. We can list the possible inputs (A and B in this case) and the outputs (O) using a **truth table as follows:**

```
XOR
A|B|O
-----
0|0|0
0|1|1
1|0|1
1|1|0

OR
A|B|O
-----
0|0|0
0|1|1
1|0|1
1|1|1

AND
A|B|O
-----
0|0|0
0|1|0
1|0|0
1|1|1
```

NOT is only 1 input, and it goes from true to false and vice versa.

In Boolean expressions, they are used like this:

```
1^((0&1&1)&/(1&0&1)\)
```

Evaluating as follows:

```
1^(( 1 |1)&/(1&0&1)\)  |  0 OR 1 = 1, order of operations left to right - no brackets
1^(( 1   )&/(1&0&1)\)  |  1 OR 1 = 1
1^(  1    &/(1&0&1)\)  |  Remove brackets
1^(  1    &/( 0 &1)\)  |  1 AND 0 = 0
1^(  1    &/( 0   )\)  |  0 AND 1 = 0
1^(  1    &/  0    \)  |  Remove brackets
1^(  1    &   1     )  |  NOT 0 = 1
1^(  1              )  |  1 AND 1 = 1
1^   1                 |  Remove brackets
0                      |  1 XOR 1 = 0
```

so 0 is the result.

**Task: create a program to do this!***

### I/O examples

```
Input -> Output
1v(0.1) -> 1
1v(0.1./1\) -> 1
/0\v(0+1) -> 0
0v1v1 -> 0
```

### Notes

- There is no order of precedence. We will treat `0.1v0+1` as `(((0.1)v0)+1)`

#### Leaderboard

```js
var QUESTION_ID=77254,OVERRIDE_USER=42854;function answersUrl(e){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: Why use non-ascii? This makes it so its hard for non-esolangs to compete.

Comment: Sorry, **esolangs

Comment: Try the sandbox !

Comment: Is this looking better now?

Comment: You should format the test cases better, at the moments it is impossible to copy & paste them all at once. Read [here](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8101/49110) for some more details on this.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Nope, there's no whitespace.

Comment: You also use `v`, but that shoudn't be XOR, since that symbol is OR in logic.

Comment: @mbomb007 What would you recommend?

Comment: Use common Boolean representations for operators like the words for `And Or Xor Not` or use `& | ^ !`.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the cutoff is for "*builtins that trivialise the problem*". General-purpose eval could be made to work by first applying some simple substitutions: should that count? The examples also include elements which aren't mentioned in the spec.

Comment: I am deleting the question and moving it to the sandbox. Is this okay?

Answer (score 1):

## GNU Sed 4.2.2, 102

Score includes +1 for `-r` option to `sed`:

```
y/+./oa/
:
s%/0\\%1%
s%/1\\|\b(0o0|(\w)v\2)%0%
s%\b(\wo\w|\wv\w|1a1)%1%
s/\b\wa\w/0/
s/\((\w)\)/\1/
t
```

[Ideone.](https://ideone.com/8aJM7h)

---

<sub>[Incomplete Retina port.](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=VGArLmByYQooYC8wXFwKMQovMVxcfFxiKDByMHwoXHcpdlwyKQowClxiKFx3clx3fFx3dlx3fDFhMSkKMQpcYlx3YVx3CjAKXCgoXHcpXCkKJDE&input=MXYoMC4xKQoxdigwLjEuLzFcKQovMFx2KDArMSkKMHYxdjEKMXYoKDArMSkuLygxLjApXCkKMC4xdjArMQ)</sub>