# Create a Boolean parser (continued)

Tags: code-golf, parsing, logic-gates

Continuation of [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77254/create-a-boolean-parser) because the author is gone and the question is closed.

---

What you need to do is create a Boolean parser.

---

Boolean expressions, in case you haven't heard of them yet, have two inputs and one output.

There are four "gates" in boolean arithmetic, namely:

- OR (represented by `|`) (binary operator, between arguments)
- AND (represented by `&`) (binary operator, between arguments)
- XOR (represented by `^`) (binary operator, between arguments)
- NOT (represented by `!`) (unary operator, argument on right)

These gates operate on their inputs which are either true (represented by `1`) or false (represented by `0`). We can list the possible inputs (`A` and `B` in this case) and the outputs (`O`) using a truth table as follows:

```
XOR
A|B|O
-----
0|0|0
0|1|1
1|0|1
1|1|0

OR
A|B|O
-----
0|0|0
0|1|1
1|0|1
1|1|1

AND
A|B|O
-----
0|0|0
0|1|0
1|0|0
1|1|1

NOT
A|O
---
0|1
1|0
```

An example input would be `1^((1|0&0)^!(1&!0&1))`, which would evaluate to:

```
 1^((1|0&0)^!(1&!0&1))
=1^(( 1 &0)^!(1&!0&1))
=1^(   0   ^!(1&!0&1))
=1^(   0   ^!(1& 1&1))
=1^(   0   ^!(  1 &1))
=1^(   0   ^!    1   )
=1^(   0   ^    0    )
=1^0
=1
```

The output would be `1`.

#### Details

- As seen in the example, there is no order of prevalence. All are evaluated from left to right, except when inside parentheses, which should be evaluated first.
- The input will only contain `()!^&|01`.
- You can choose any 8-byte character to replace the 8 characters above, but they must have a 1-to-1 mapping and must be stated.
- Specifically, the function `eval` is not allowed to be used on any string **derived from the input**. Specifically, the function `input` (or the equivalent in the language) and any function that calls it cannot be used by `eval`. You also cannot concatenate the `input` into your string inside the `eval`.

#### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest solution in bytes wins.

Comment: Cheddar has a built in to generate a call stack from a string is that disallowed too?

Comment: Could you add some more test cases?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ What test case would you like to see?

Comment: @KennyLau A few complicated ones, idk

Comment: Is there any condition that the test case did not handle? I think it pretty much handled everything already.

Comment: @KennyLau Considering that there are only 2 outputs, a program could still fail some cases even if it passes one test case.

Comment: I deliberately designed `1|0&0` so that if they evaluate `&` first, the output will fail.

Comment: Is `eval` disallowed even when it's not used on input data at all, but instead to golf the parser?

Comment: @orlp Is it clear enough now? People will just find loopholes if I make it too explicit (I forgot the name of the phenomenon).

Comment: @KennyLau I think you should explicitly say that the input is given as a string (and not any other epression, otherwise you could just use an *identity* function in many languages).

Comment: About testcases: with just 1 or 0 for output I can just put a random function and I will be right 50% of times

Comment: @edc65 Please do provide me with more testcases (just the input, I will produce the output) in case of doubt.

Comment: are 2 or more consecutive `!` allowed? ie `!!1`

Comment: `eval` won't help as there are different operator priorities.

Comment: @JackAmmo Yes, though I do not see how that would posit any problem.

Comment: @KennyLau it's not so much a problem as verifying a case that needs to be dealt with

Comment: Not enough test cases. Testing my script on your input is just one test case, no matter how complex your test case is. I might get the right output despite getting wrong output on other cases.

Comment: One test case should make sure the script parses left-to-right instead of all false substrings first; another should make sure it parses left-to-right instead of all true substrings first; another should make sure it parses left-to-right instead of using the usual order of operations. (That last can probably be combined with one of the others.) Another should use `!!`.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6) 116 bytes

**edit** thx @user81655 for 3 bytes saved and a bug found

```js
s=>[...s].map(x=>x<2?v=m[x]:x<6?m=[,,m[1]+m[0],0+v,v+1,v+(1^v)][x]:x>6?v=o.pop()[v]:m=o.push(m)&&a,o=[v=a=m='01'])|v
```

Probably not the best approach, but no eval and no boolean operators, just truth tables.

Character used:

- ! -> 2
- & -> 3
- | -> 4
- ^ -> 5
- ( -> 6
- ) -> 7

**Test**

```js
f=s=>[...s].map(x=>x<2?v=m[x]:x<6?m=[,,m[1]+m[0],0+v,v+1,v+(1^v)][x]:x>6?v=o.pop()[v]:m=o.push(m)&&a,o=[v=a=m='01'])|v

console.log=(...x)=>O.textContent+=x+'\n'

test=[ ["1^((1|0&0)^!(1&!0&1))",1] 
// be more careful, step by step
,["0&0",0],["0&1",0],["1&0",0],["1&1",1]
,["0|0",0],["0|1",1],["1|0",1],["1|1",1]
,["0^0",0],["0^1",1],["1^0",1],["1^1",0]
,["0&!0",0],["0&!1",0],["1&!0",1],["1&!1",0]
,["0|!0",1],["0|!1",0],["1|!0",1],["1|!1",1]
,["0^!0",1],["0^!1",0],["1^!0",0],["1^!1",1]
,["!0&0",0],["!0&1",1],["!1&0",0],["!1&1",0]
,["!0|0",1],["!0|1",1],["!1|0",0],["!1|1",1]
,["!0^0",1],["!0^1",0],["!1^0",0],["!1^1",1]
// nand, nor
,["!(0&0)",1],["!(0&1)",1],["!(1&0)",1],["!(1&1)",0]
,["!(0|0)",1],["!(0|1)",0],["!(1|0)",0],["!(1|1)",0]
     ]

test.forEach(([x,check]) => {
  // remap operators (each one on its line, just to be clear)
  var t = x.replace(/!/g,"2")
  t = t.replace(/&/g,"3")
  t = t.replace(/\|/g,"4")
  t = t.replace(/\^/g,"5")
  t = t.replace(/\(/g,"6")
  t = t.replace(/\)/g,"7")
  r = f(t)
  console.log((r==check?'OK':'KO')+' '+x +' '+r)
})
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Comment: Did you really mean `x>7`?

Comment: `r=f(x.replace(/./g,c=>"01!&|^()".indexOf(c)))`

Comment: @Neil I'll check, thanks. Of course if >6

Comment: @Neil I'm adding test cases. I'm quite sure that given associativity and commutativity of the operators, the NOT should always work

Comment: It took me some time to work out why (say) `0|!0` works, but now I do, have my upvote.

Comment: Wow. My own solution was just at 299 btes.

Answer (score 6):

## Retina, 49 bytes

```
+`(<1>|!0|1[ox]0|0[ox]1|1[ao]1)|<0>|!1|\d\w\d
$#1
```

I have no idea how did it come out so short.

Character mapping:

```
^ -> x
& -> a
| -> o
( -> <
) -> >
```

`1`, `0`, and `!` are left unchanged.

This works by replacing all truthy expressions (single `1` in parentheses, `!0`, `1&1`, `1^0`, `0|1`, etc.) with `1`, and all other (single `0` in parentheses, `!1`, `1&0`, `1^1`, `0|0`, etc.) with `0`.

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=K2AoPDE-fCEwfDFbb3hdMHwwW294XTF8MVthb10xKXw8MD58ITF8XGRcd1xkCiQjMQ&input=MXg8PDFvMGEwPnghPDFhITBhMT4-)
[Try it online with automatic character mapping!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=VGBeJnwoKWB4YVxvPD4KK2AoPDE-fCEwfDFbb3hdMHwwW294XTF8MVthb10xKXw8MD58ITF8XGRcd1xkCiQjMQ&input=MV4oKDF8MCYwKV4hKDEmITAmMSkp)

Answer (score 3):

## grep + shell utils, 131 bytes

```
rev|grep -cP '^(((0|R((?9)(x(?1)|a(?4))|(?2)([oxa](?4)|a(?1)|))L|(1|R(?1)L)!)(!!)*)[xo](?1)|(1|R(?1)L|(?2)!)([ao](?1)|[xo](?4)|))$'
```

The following chars are renamed:

```
( -> L
) -> R
| -> o
& -> a
^ -> x
```

I started trying to write a grep solution, but discovered that it did not work well with the left-associative infix operators. I needed to have a pattern like (chain of operators) = (chain of operators) (binary op) (single operand), but this contains a possible infinite recursion, so grep refuses to execute it. But I noticed that I *could* parse right-associative operators. This made the `!` operator a pain, but it was still possible. So I made a regex for calculating backwards boolean expressions, and sent the input through `rev`. The regex itself, which matches true expressions, is 116 bytes.

TODO: choose different characters for the input so that I can distinguish all the used groups of operators with built-in character classes.

Comment: What does `(?9)` mean?

Comment: It means take the 9th capturing group and re-execute it (as distinct from `\9` which would mean to match what the 9th capturing group matched). So for instance `(\d)\1` matches the same digit twice, while `(\d)(\?1)` matches any two digits.

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 210 bytes

```
from operator import*;
def t(o):c=o.pop(0);return ord(c)-48if c in"01"else[p(o),o.pop(0)][0]if"("==c else 1-t(o)
def p(o):
 v=t(o)
 while o and")"!=o[0]:v=[xor,or_,and_]["^|&".index(o.pop(0))](v,t(o))
 return v
```

Really bad recursive descent, I expect this to be beaten in a heartbeat.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, <s>139</s> 129 bytes

```
a=StringPartition;StringReplace[#,{"(0)0&00&11&00|00^01^1"~a~3|"!1"->"0","(1)1&10|11|01|10^11^0"~a~3|"!0"->"1"},1]&~FixedPoint~#&
```

A simple string-replacement solution scores far better than I hoped for.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript ES6, 223 bytes

```
x=>(Q=[],S=[],[...x].map(t=>{q=+t&&Q.push(t);if(t==")")while((a=S.pop())!="(")Q.push(a);else if(!q)S.push(t)}),k=[],p=_=>k.pop(),Q.concat(S.reverse()).map(e=>k.push(+e||e<"#"?1-p():e<"'"?p()&p():e<","?p()|p():p()^p())),p())
```

Uses a shunting yard algorithm.

```
x=>(Q=[],S=[],[...x].map(t=>{q=+t&&Q.push(t);if(t==")")while((a=S.pop())!="(")Q.push(a);else 
if(!q)S.push(t)}),k=[],p=_=>k.pop(),Q.concat(S.reverse()).map(e=>k.push(+e||e<"#"?1-p():e<"'"
?p()&p():e<","?p()|p():p()^p())),p())
```

Uses `+` for OR, `!` for negation, `^` for XOR, and `&` for and. `0` and `1` are used for their respective values. Sure, I could golf some by making the operators numbers, but I'm not winning the JavaScript prize even if I do, so I thought I'd make it at least somewhat readable and correct.

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 459 bytes

```java
String p(String s){int x,y;while((y=s.indexOf("b"))>=0){x=s.lastIndexOf("a",y);s=s.replaceAll(s.subString(x,y+1),p(s.subString(x+1,y)));}String t,a="1",b="0";while(s.indexOf("!")>=0){s=s.replaceAll("!0",a);s=s.replaceAll("!1",b);}while(s.length()>1){t=s.subString(0,3);if(t.charAt(1)=='l')s=s.replaceFirst(t,t.equals("0l0")?b:a);else if(t.charAt(1)=='&')s=s.replaceFirst(t,t.equals("1&1")?a:b);else s=s.replaceFirst(t,t.charAt(0)==t.charAt(2)?b:a);}return s;}
```

`AND` is `&`

`OR` is `l`(lowercase L)

`XOR` is `x` (or any other character that happens to play nice with `String`'s methods such as `String.replaceAll(...)`)

`NOT` is `!`

`(` is `a`

`)` is `b`

here's a more readable version:

```java
String parseBoolean( String str ) {
    int start,end;
    //look for matching brackets ab
    while( (end = str.indexOf( "b" )) >= 0 ) {
        start = str.lastIndexOf( "a", end );
        str = str.replaceAll( str.subString( start, end + 1 ), parseBoolean( str.subString( start + 1, end ) ) );
    }
    String temp, one = "1", zero = "0";
    //handle all the !'s
    while( str.indexOf( "!" ) >= 0 ) {
        str = str.replaceAll( "!0", one );
        str = str.replaceAll( "!1", zero );
    }
    //handle the remaining operators from left to right
    while( str.length() > 1 ){
        temp = str.subString( 0, 3 );
        //check for OR
        if( temp.charAt( 1 ) == 'l' )
            str = str.replaceFirst( temp, temp.equals( "0l0" ) ? zero : one );
        //check for AND
        else if(t.charAt(1)=='&')
            str = str.replaceFirst( temp, temp.equals( "1&1" ) ? one : zero );
        //handle XOR
        else 
            str = str.replaceFirst( temp, temp.charAt( 0 ) == temp.charAt( 2 ) ? zero : one );
    }
    return str;
}
```

[try it online](http://ideone.com/YQDh1V)

Comment: As always with Java golfing, my favorite thing to do is replace char literals with their integer counterparts wherever I can. In this case, that would be in both the regular indexOfs, and the charAt comparisons. Also, if you change the character for AND to "n" instead of "&", you can use < or > statements with single ifs when checking for which operation you need to do.

Comment: Oh, one more thing. You can double up on the call to replaceAll in the second while loop, also saving you those brackets.

Comment: @Blue i always forget to char literals to ints, thanks. I'm not quite sure what you mean on doubling up on the replaceAll call for the !'s.

Comment: s=s.replaceAll("!0",a).replaceAll("!1",b);

Answer (score 1):

## C, 247

Golfed:

```c
b(char*s){int i,j,k,l;if(*s==40){for(j=i=1;i+=s[++j]==41?-1:s[j]==40?1:0,i;);s[j++]=0;b(s+1);sprintf(s,"%s%s",s+1,s+j);}!s[1]?:(b(s+1),i=*s,j=1,k=s[1],i>47&i<50?:(s[1]=i==33?(j=0,k^1):(l=s[-1],i==38?k&l:i==94?k^l|'0':k|l),sprintf(s-j,"%s",s+1)));}
```

Ungolfed, with `main()` (takes expression as 1st arg). The golfed version has no debugging printfs and uses 2-digit ascii codes instead of char literals (`40 == '('`). I could have saved some characters by mapping `()|^&!` to `234567` - this would have made many manipulations and tests easier after subtracting `48` from each.

```c
char*z;                 // tracks recursion depth; not used in golfed version
b(char*s){
    int i,j,k,l;
    printf("%u> '%s'\n", s-z, s);
    if(*s=='('){        // handles parenthesis
        for(j=i=1;i+=s[++j]==')'?-1:s[j]=='('?1:0,i;);
        s[j++]=0;
        b(s+1);         // s+1 to s+j gets substituted for its evaluation
        sprintf(s,"%s%s",s+1,s+j);
    }
    !s[1]?:(            // if 1 char left, return
        b(s+1),         // evaluate rest of expression
        i=*s,
        j=1,
        k=s[1],
        printf("%u: '%c'\n", s-z, i),
        i>47&i<50?:(    // if 0 or 1, skip substitution
                        // otherwise, perform boolean operation
            s[1]=i=='!'?(j=0,k^1):(l=s[-1],i=='&'?k&l:i=='|'?k|l:k^l|'0'),
                        // and replace operation with result
            sprintf(s-j,"%s",s+1),printf("%u= '%s'\n", s-z, s-j)));
    printf("%u< '%s'\n", s-z, s);
}
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char *s;    
    sscanf(argv[1],"%ms",&s);
    z=s;
    b(s);
    printf("%s => %s\n", argv[1], s);
}
```

Comment: +1 for `for(j=i=1;i+=s[++j]==')'?-1:s[j]=='('?1:0,i;);`.

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 218

Uses pattern-matching, but avoids the out-of-order replacements of my previous failed Java attempt (sharp eyes there, [@Kenny Lau](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48934/kenny-lau)!).

Golfed:

```c
String e(String s){Matcher m=Pattern.compile("(<1>|1o[01]|0o1|1a1|1x0|0x1|n0)|(<0>|0o0|0a[01]|1a0|1x1|0x0|n1)").matcher(s);return m.find()?e(s.substring(0,m.start())+(m.group(1)==null?"0":"1")+s.substring(m.end())):s;}
```

Ungolfed, reads input from arguments and applies the mapping `oaxn` for `|&^!` and `<>` for `()`:

```c
import java.util.regex.*;

public class B{
    String e(String s){
        System.out.println(s);
        Matcher m=Pattern
            .compile(
                "(<1>|1o[01]|0o1|1a1|1x0|0x1|n0)|"+
                "(<0>|0o0|0a[01]|1a0|1x1|0x0|n1)")
            .matcher(s);
        return m.find()?e(s.substring(0,m.start())+(m.group(1)==null?"0":"1")+s.substring(m.end())):s;
    }
    
    public static String map(String s, String ... replacements) {
        for (String r: replacements) {
            s = s.replace(r.substring(0,1), r.substring(1));
        }
        return s;
    }
    
    public static void main(String ... args){
        for (String s: args) System.out.println(new B().e(
            map(s,"(<",")>","|o","&a","!n","^x")
        ));
    }
}
```

Java's `m.group(i)` tells you which group matched; the 1st group is for true substitutions and the 2nd one for false ones. This is iterated in strict left-to-right order until no substitutions are performed.