# Which languages are optimal for problems that require "reading" input while also writing to it like a stack

Tags: code-golf, tips

When encountering a problem whose input is meant to be read sequentially, *but you may also want to push back onto the input like a stack*, which languages have the optimal boilerplates for doing so, and how?

For example, from [Create a Boolean Calculator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207084/create-a-boolean-calculator), we have a string like:

```
1AND0OR1XOR1
```

We want to "pop" 5 chars `1AND0`, compute it to be `0`, then "push" it back to form:

```
0OR1XOR1
```

Then, repeat until there's only 1 char left. In this case:

```
0
```

It's trivial to write `while` loops and such, but this seems common enough in codegolf problems that there must be canonical forms. I wasn't able to find a [tips](/questions/tagged/tips) question specifically about this setup though, and going through each [tips](/questions/tagged/tips) question by language was difficult.

Comment: I think this question is very difficult to answer without a specific language tag. The answer will vary wildly based on the length of keywords and the language paradigm. I haven't VTC yet, but I think this is probably lacking focus unless you specify a language.

Comment: Hm, I guess I was hoping to pick my golfing language for these types of questions by knowing which was best at it.

Comment: I see, then it may be reasonable if you rephrase this as "in which language is doing task X the shortest" (that way it has a precise answer). I think that would probably make it the first of its kind though, so I'd advise asking something on meta. I'm wrong often enough about what the majority wants here so I wouldn't trust just me!

Comment: Why not write a challenge that requires this trick to be used? You basically want to sequentially replace a string prefix so if you require each step in the output you should find the best way to do that among the competing languages.

Comment: @FryTheEggman Isn't that basically [tag:code-golf] in a nutshell? :)

Comment: Instead of trying to "push back onto the input like a stack", why not just read all the input into a stack, and them work on the stack normally? In your example, you would pop the top five chars and push `0`, etc. Some languages have a stack paradigm, so this is easy. For non-stack oriented languages, you can simulate a stack with an array or list

Comment: @Sanchises - Haha, that's a good idea. But likely if it became a real problem, I'd have to specify it much more tightly (what operations, etc.) or it would _really_ have to be closed.

Comment: @LuisMendo - Yup, that was my "naive" idea. But for the Boolean problem I linked for example, I realized I need to start with the tiniest boilerplate possible to have even a chance at winning, scorewise. That's why I wanted to know what languages / techniques are hyperoptimized for this task.

Comment: This is probably much better approached with recursion either by functions like Haskell, (curry although has better pattern matching for this sort of thing), or predicates like in Prolog.  While loops are pretty bad for expressing this sort of thing.

Comment: This looks totally on-topic for a tips question. Selecting a language is part of golfing, and the feature being asked for is pretty specific.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman - I think I accidentally deleted my reply. Yep, that makes a better title, thanks!

Comment: But you don't want to read 5 characters -- you can only know you need 5 characters once you've inspected the second (and the fifth). For `1OR0`, you need 4. For `1ANDNOT0`, you need 8. Reading a fixed number of characters is a whole different problem then reading a number of tokens (and with the given challenge as example, it's not even a fixed number of tokens due to the existence of `NOT`).

Comment: @Abigail - Ah, I realized that was a bad example. An array of inputs works as well; I just didn't want answers to think only in terms of arrays.

Answer (score 3):

The approach you're asking seems like reduce/left fold in general. Many languages have this, such as Python (`reduce(f,seq)` or `functools.reduce(f,seq)`), APL (`f⍨/⌽seq`), Jelly (`f/seq`), and Haskell (`foldl f start seq`).

As a Python example, let's assume we already have the input parsed as a list `seq=[1, 'AND', 0, 'OR', 1, 'XOR', 1]`. Then `reduce(f,seq)` is equivalent to

```
f(f(f(f(f(f(1, 'AND'), 0), 'OR'), 1), 'XOR'), 1)
```

The trouble here is that we need to take 3 arguments at a time. A way this could be done is by grouping most of the sequence into pairs `seq2=[1, ['AND',0], ['OR',1], ['XOR',1]]`, so `reduce(f,seq)` would be equivalent to

```
f(f(f(1, ['AND',0]), ['OR',1]), ['XOR',1])
```

This could work well in Jelly because it has a builtin `s` that could help [split into pairs](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzlnFRkDi6KSHO2f8//8/2lBHQd3Rz0VdR8EAyPIPAjJAQhEQViwA) (output looks funny strings are internally lists of chars).

However, a loop-based approach would work better in Python by assigning to a slice of an array:

```
seq=[1, 'AND', 0, 'OR', 1, 'XOR', 1]
while len(seq)>1:
  seq[1:3] = [f(*seq[1:3])]
print(seq[0])
```

This would output `f(f(f(1, 'AND', 0), 'OR', 1), 'XOR', 1)`.

As @AdHocGarfHunter notes in the comments, recursion is a good idea too:

```
# (ungolfed)
def r(s):
  if len(s)>1:
    return r(f(*s[:3]) + s[3:])
  else:
    return s[0]
```

APL has little boilerplate for this: `{1=⍴⍵:⊃⍵⋄∇(3↓⍵),f3↑⍵}` (`∇` is the recursion). Jelly does too, with `1` byte recursion.